# Select all relationships between two models - dbt

Tags: dbt

I understand the syntax and selection methods available in DBT but can't seem to understand if it's possible to select all models between two potential models.

For example, let's assume model A is near the start of the DAG and model B is near the end. In between, both of these models relate to hundreds of other models, but I only want to select the models that both A AND B relate to (not just the models that both A OR B relate to).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dbt run -s A+,+B
```

Explanation:

- A+ is all models downstream of A
- +B is all models upstream of B
- The comma between them selects the intersection of the two